# My application is not working when it is minimised in iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios4

What should I do to rum my application continuously in the background even though it is minimised? Right now my app is running on mainthread itself. Do I need to create one more thread and need to run my logic on that thread?

Answer (score 1):

Only certain types of background tasks are allowed in iOS (audio, location, and VoIP, plus "task completion" and notifications) — detailed information can be found in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Comment: My app is using corelocation concepts, eventhough it is not working when it is minimised.